# filter vs map reactjs and jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react project to learn react.

In a component's render method, when I use `.map` to iterate over values and return an array of components, everything works as expected.

```
<ol className="books-grid">
        {              
          books && books.map((book, index) => {
            if (book.shelf === shelf) {
              return (
                <Book key={book && book.id ? book.id : index} changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf} book={book} />
              );
            }
          })}
      </ol>
```

But when I use `filter`:

```
<ol className="books-grid">
            {              
              books && books.filter((book, index) => {
                if (book.shelf === shelf) {
                  return (
                    <Book key={book && book.id ? book.id : index} changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf} book={book} />
                  );
                }
              })}
          </ol>
```

I get the error (which I've researched)

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`

I don't understand why `filter` is throwing this error vs `map`? Is there something unique to react and `.map`? Both return an array.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the book object in both cases as received in the filter and map callback arrow functions as argument? I am most positive you will see some differences.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Array.filter` does not allow you to transform the data into components. That is the job of `Array.map`.

You should instead filter first, then chain the map call afterward:

```
{              
  books && books
    .filter(book => book.shelf === shelf)
    .map((book, index) => {
      return (
        <Book
           key={book && book.id ? book.id : index}
           changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf}
           book={book} />
      );
    })
}
```

If you want to avoid a second pass over your list of `books`, you can return `null` as well, though this is "less good" because you're forcing React to render `null` when it doesn't need to do any work at all:

```
{              
  books && books
    .map((book, index) => {
      if (book.shelf !== shelf) {
        return null;
      }
      return (
        <Book
           key={book && book.id ? book.id : index}
           changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf}
           book={book} />
      );
    })
}
```

Comment: If you want one pass you should use `reduce`

Comment: this answer is good but for me I needed to use includes(), I'll post my answer version below

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing unique to React and `map()` or `filter()`.

In the first example when using `map()` you are returning an array of React components which are rendered in the DOM. You are transforming (mapping) each plain JavaScript object in the array into a React component. As a matter of fact, you are also going to return some `undefined` elements in the resulting array, if the condition `book.shelf === shelf` is falsy. Your array may look like `[<Book />, <Book />, undefined, <Book />, undefined]`. That's not such a big deal, since React won't render falsy values (`null` or `undefined` elements will just be skipped).

The second example won't return the same result (an array of React components), but an array of plain JavaScript objects (of type book). This is because no matter what are you returning from the filter function, it's going to be cast to a `Boolean` value - `true` or `false` and that value is going to decide if the current element is going to be filtered or not. The result of your `.filter()` function is going to be something like this (imagine `shelf === 'Science'`):

```
Original array: [{ shelf: "Science" }, { shelf: "Thrillers" }, { shelf: "Informatics" }]
Filtered array: [{ shelf: "Science" }]
```

As you can see, the items in the array won't be React components (`<Book />`) and React won't be able to render them in the DOM, thus the error it throws.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use one pass over the array you can use reduce:

```
books && books
.reduce(
  (all,book, index) => {
    if (book.shelf !== shelf) {
      return all;
    }
    return all.concat(
      <Book
        key={book && book.id ? book.id : index}
        changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf}
        book={book} />
    );
  }
  ,[]
)
```

However; I think using `filter` and `map` makes for code that's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to me seems good but I needed to use `includes()` in order to work, also maybe a good idea to use `toLowerCase()`:

```
{              
  books && books
    .filter(book => book.shelf.toLowerCase().includes(shelf.toLowerCase()))
    .map((book, index) => {
      return (
        <Book
           key={book && book.id ? book.id : index}
           changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf}
           book={book} />
      );
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same error. then, I also wrap my `map` method on `filter` method which helps me to solve the error and accept it as react valid child.

```
<ul className="menu">
            {navigationLinks?.filter((eachNavigation) => {
              if (eachNavigation.select.length < 1) {
                return eachNavigation;
              }
            }).map((eachNavigation, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className="menu__list menu__list--noSelect">
                  <a href={eachNavigation.link}>{eachNavigation.title}</a>
                </li>
              )
            })
            }
          </ul>
```

```js
<ul className="menu">
                {navigationLinks?.filter((eachNavigation) => {
                  if (eachNavigation.select.length < 1) {
                    return eachNavigation;
                  }
                }).map((eachNavigation, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index} className="menu__list menu__list--noSelect">
                      <a href={eachNavigation.link}>{eachNavigation.title}</a>
                    </li>
                  )
                })
                }
              </ul>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30543663)