# filter table by value with react redux and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to filter a table in a react component by a value inside a document in firebase.

The important code looks like this. Claims is being parsed into another component for the table rows.

```
class Claims extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getClaims();
  }
  render() {
    const { Claims, loading } = this.props.data;
    let recentClaimsMarkup = !loading ? (
      Claims.map(Claim => <ClaimsTable Claim={Claim} />)
    ) : (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Paper className = {mergeClasses.root}>
          <Typography> {this.props.match.params.Project} Claim's</Typography>{" "}
        </Paper>
        <Paper className={mergeClasses.root}>
          <Table className={mergeClasses.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Claim ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Date received</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Progress</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Edit Claim</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>{recentClaimsMarkup}</TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
```

I am wanting to filter it by the url Project, shown below

```
{this.props.match.params.Project}
```

This is due to the claims being tied to the project name.

If this was in Python I would just use a for loop or something similar, but a little bit confused how to filter what Claims are able to be mapped.

Basically want it to be, for claims with Project == {this.props.match.params.Project}: map claims.

Appreciate any help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically filter also returns a new copy of array and you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123310/filter-vs-map-reactjs-and-jsx), but the problem is you can't create the jsx element, if you want to know more 
you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123310/filter-vs-map-reactjs-and-jsx)

so in your case you need to first filter and then you need to render the jsx element using map like shown below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const User = props => {
  const claimsUserHasAccess = props.data.claims.filter(
    claim => claim.project === props.match.params.access
  );
  return (
    <>
      {claimsUserHasAccess.map(claim => (
        <p key={claim.name}>{claim.name}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const userData = {
  claims: [
    { project: "enabled", name: "job" },
    { project: "enabled", name: "nick" },
    { project: "disabled", name: "jef" }
  ]
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/user/:access"
          render={props => <User data={userData} {...props} />}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

in the url you need to enter enabled or disabled to see the users. I hope this will give a better view of your problem.

working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59368418-so-cioir)